# Yii: Custom crud/admin URL

Tags: php, yii

At the moment my Yii crud/admin interfaces exist on a URL like this.

```
http://local:8080/index.php/people
```

I would like them to exist on an admin URL

```
http://local:8080/index.php/admin/people
```

I'm sure this is possible but can't find any solutions in documentations

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Or it would be much more convinient to have all your backend functionality withing separate admin [module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module). You can easily generate its main CRUD layout with [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#using-gii) tool.

Answer (score 3):

In common, you can use Yii router (urlManager) settings to customize your paths (this topic covered at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

In your case you can use something like this (I dont know your concrete configuration at this place, so I try to guess):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Comment: This works but the people admin is still available under both /people/admin and /people rather odd.